# Is it a good idea to have base Roles and Permissions names like class constants?

Tags: php, security, authentication, permissions

I'd like to have base user Roles and base Permissions for both of them.
I decided to create separate classes that would store them inside like constants.
Application will have only Companies, Applications(similar to web-sites), Users (assigned to companies), Roles and Permissions as domain models. Tables and relation tables are the same. Extra Roles can be added in the future but they'll have these permissons.

Super Admin can do anything, Admin can do anything related to the company he is assigned to and User can just read user's info.

Application will most likely be used only as Rest API for other web-sites.

I'd like to know is it a good idea to have such classes with constants in order to check the user's permission in my code? Like $user->hasPermissionTo(PermissionType::COMPANY_ADD) or $user->hasRole(RoleType::SUPER_ADMIN). What problems can I run into?

Thanks a lot!!!

This is PermissionType class that has base permissions for application.

```
final class PermissionType {
    const USER_READ   = 'user.read';
    const USER_ADD    = 'user.add';
    const USER_UPDATE = 'user.update';
    const USER_DELETE = 'user.delete';

    const APP_READ   = 'app.read';
    const APP_ADD    = 'app.add';
    const APP_UPDATE = 'app.update';
    const APP_DELETE = 'app.delete';

    const COMPANY_READ   = 'company.read';
    const COMPANY_ADD    = 'company.add';
    const COMPANY_UPDATE = 'company.update';
    const COMPANY_DELETE = 'company.delete';

    const ROLE_READ   = 'role.read';
    const ROLE_ADD    = 'role.add';
    const ROLE_UPDATE = 'role.update';
    const ROLE_DELETE = 'role.delete';
```

}

This is base RoleType class that has default roles' names and default permissions for each of them

```
final class RoleType {
    const USER        = 'user';
    const ADMIN       = 'admin';
    const SUPER_ADMIN = 'super_admin';

    const DEFAULT_ROLE_PERMISSIONS = [
        self::USER         => [Permission::USER_READ],
        self::ADMIN        => [
            Permission::USER_READ,
            Permission::USER_ADD,
            Permission::USER_UPDATE,
            Permission::USER_DELETE,
            Permission::APP_READ,
            Permission::APP_ADD,
            Permission::APP_UPDATE,
            Permission::APP_DELETE,
            Permission::COMPANY_READ,
            Permission::COMPANY_ADD,
            Permission::COMPANY_UPDATE,
            Permission::COMPANY_DELETE,
            Permission::ROLE_READ,
            Permission::ROLE_ADD,
            Permission::ROLE_UPDATE,
            Permission::ROLE_DELETE,
        ],
        self::SUPER_ADMIN  => [
            Permission::USER_READ,
            Permission::USER_ADD,
            Permission::USER_UPDATE,
            Permission::USER_DELETE,
            Permission::APP_READ,
            Permission::APP_ADD,
            Permission::APP_UPDATE,
            Permission::APP_DELETE,
            Permission::COMPANY_READ,
            Permission::COMPANY_ADD,
            Permission::COMPANY_UPDATE,
            Permission::COMPANY_DELETE,
            Permission::ROLE_READ,
            Permission::ROLE_ADD,
            Permission::ROLE_UPDATE,
            Permission::ROLE_DELETE,
    ]
];
```

}

Comment: You should probably store this kind of stuff in the database, managing your permissions this way is going to get crazy.

Comment: of course I'll store it in database but my code should understand does particular user have permission\access to do some action like creating a user. So I want use constants in code in cases like $user->hasPermissionTo(PermissionType::USER_ADD) where I can make some checks (like comparing current user permissions with requested). But I don't have much exprience with it and I wanna know future drawbacks or other opportunities. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The idea where you're limiting to a single function is a good approach, it will offer lots of flexibility.

Comment: @Augwa I also found good article about how to properly handle permissions and don't rely on roles but activities. Here is a link https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/